# iOS peripheral service still empty after discovering

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, swift2, cbperipheral

I am trying to use Bluetooth
I have something like this :

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    Connected = true
    TableView.reloadData()
    Activityview.stopAnimating()
    TabBar.topItem!.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Suivant", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: nil, action: #selector(Connexion.next))
    CM.stopScan()
    Scanning = false
    Refresh_Button.setTitle("Deconnecté", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    let AlertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Connecté", message: "Le module est bien connecté", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let ActionAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { (action) in }
    AlertMessage.addAction(ActionAlert)
    self.presentViewController(AlertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    peripheral.delegate = self
    let servicetoFind = CBUUID(string: "19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214")
    peripheral.discoverServices([servicetoFind])
}
```

My service function :

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
    print("found service")
    print(peripheral)
    print(peripheral.services)
    print(error)
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        print("Searching for charac...")
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service)
    }
}
```

my Service is found and I got in console :

```
found service
<CBPeripheral: 0x13ce1c430, identifier = F39F9D5D-98FE-A350-17BD-21C1185E2089, name = GENUINO 101-1E2D, state = connected>
Optional([])
nil
```

Why my services for my peripheral is still empty after discovering but got no error ?

Any ideas ?

thanks !

Comment: Have you saved your `peripheral` in a property, perhaps in `didDiscover,,` which isn't shown here?

Comment: I record all peripheral found into an array of CBPeripheral like this : Peripherals.append(peripheral). But i am not using them yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I restarted my iPhone and all work very good now... Thanks guys !

Comment: I've just wasted hours on this! My backgrounded peripheral was discovered and connected to when using my service UUID, but `didDiscoverServices` returned no services. A restart fixed it.

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon. It worked all day yesterday in the background fine. Today I used Xcode to run a new version of the app on both devices, and i'm back to not being able to get the background service even though it discovers it. I've restarted both devices many times :(

Comment: Maybe disable/enable BT ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be nil. You should only check for services under the for loop you're using. Since you're not getting any service, you can also try peripheral.discoverServices(nil). It will list all the services.

Comment: I alteady tried with nil parameter and iOS just find 0 service. But if I use my service in parameter, iOS find the service I got one my Peripheral. I understood that iOS add service in peripheral.services for all service found and can be use directly in this handler : "didDiscoverservice"

Comment: @LoganGallois If you are not getting any services then there are no services and you should create a service and add it to your peripheral.

Comment: I am getting one because I got the message "found service" in "didDiscoverservice"

Comment: It will be called when you call discoverServices method but you should check the services using the peripheral only.

Comment: Oh ok. So how I use the peripheral only ? With discoverService(nil) ?

Comment: using peripheral.services, the one you're using in for statement.

Comment: I don't get it :/ peripheral.services is nil so i can't use it because I didn't check services